# Why I can't retrieve images from storage in my Laravel App?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I can't retrieve images that I upload in local
I don't know why, in production it runs correctly
But in local don't work
The project is not mine, it's a legacy project
Maybe I forgot to run some command?
I already run storage:link command

I have a form to post a property like a house, department, duplex, etc
It has a featured image, and a collection of photos

I use the [MediaUploader](https://laravel-mediable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploader.html) library
It has a mediable table and a media table, everything is working fine
The media is registered in database and saved in the route storage/public/properties
But when I try to retrieve it, I get the path but is not rendered in the view, looks like the path is wrong, but it is ok because in production website it works fine

My controller code:

```
    $featuredImage = MediaUploader::fromSource($request->file('featured_image')) 
             ->setMaximumSize(2097152) 
             ->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']) 
             ->toDestination('public', 'uploads/properties') 
             ->upload();
    $newProperty->attachMedia($featuredImage, 'property_thumbnail');

    foreach ($request->validated()['images'] as $photo) {
        $image = MediaUploader::fromSource($photo)
                        ->setMaximumSize(2097152)
                        ->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'])
                        ->toDestination('public', 'uploads/properties')
                        ->upload();
        
        $newProperty->attachMedia($image, 'property');
    }
```

`

The code to retrieve it in Model

```
// obtener la foto destacada de una propiedad 
public function thumbnail() 
{ 
    return $this->getMedia('property_thumbnail'); 
}

// obtener las fotos de una propiedad
public function photos()
{
    return $this->getMedia('property');
}
```

`

My filesystem config file:
`'public' => [`

`'driver' => 'local',`

`'root' => storage_path('app/public'),`

`'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',`

`'visibility' => 'public',`

`],`

My folder structure
[image]

The path saved in database
[image]

Comment: have you linked your storage with public ?

Comment: php artisan storage:link is already

Comment: or you mean something else?

Comment: what is the path of image after rendering ?

Comment: http://localhost/storage/uploads/properties/casa-1.jpg

Comment: I have a laragon server and a Windows 10 SO

Comment: *But when I try to retrieve it, I get the path but is not rendered in the view, looks like the path is wrong...* Could you show us how you're retrieving it from your *view* file?